# Versão do MySql.Data.Entity compativel com o MySql 5.6

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

Quais as versões do:

- MySql.Data
- MySql.Data.Entity
- EF

Compativel com a versão 5.6 do MySql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei a seguinte tabela na [documentação do MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-visual-studio-install.html). Ele mostra qual a versão do MySQL for Visual Studio é necessária de acordo com a versão do servidor, Connector e Visual Studio:

```
 MySQL for Visual Studio | Connector/Net | Visual Studio          | MySQL Server            | Observações                         
-------------------------|---------------|------------------------|-------------------------|-------------------------------------
 1.2                     | 6.9,6.8       | 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013 | 5.7, 5.6, 5.5, 5.1, 5.0 | Requer algumas funções do C/Net 6.9 
 1.1                     | 6.8           | 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013 | 5.7, 5.6, 5.5, 5.1, 5.0 |                                     
 1.0                     | 6.7           | 2008, 2010, 2012       | 5.7, 5.6, 5.5, 5.1, 5.0 |
```